# Code not Returning same data as SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, vbscript

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 which when I run in SSMS it returns my data perfectly. When I call the stored procedure from the VB script code, it does not return data.

Stored procedure code:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[getstuff]
    (@CompID int = NULL,
     @FranID int = NULL,
     @Type nvarchar (50) = NULL)
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table1
    WHERE CompID = @CompID
      AND (FranID = @FranID OR @FranID IS NULL)
      AND (PType = @Type OR @Type IS NULL)
```

I run the stored procedure manually in SSMS like -

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[getstuff]
     @CompID = 1,
     @FranID = 22,
     @Type = NULL
```

I get the exact data I am expecting

When I run in VBScript like so -

```
    strSql = "getstuff"
    DBConn.AddParameter "@CompID", 1
    DBConn.AddParameter "@FranID", 22
    DBConn.AddParameter "@Type", NULL       

    Set TestRS = DBConn.GetRecordset(adCmdStoredProc, strSQL)
```

I get no data back. But if I run like so without the @Type Parameter -

```
    strSql = "getstuff"
    DBConn.AddParameter "@CompID", 1
    DBConn.AddParameter "@FranID", 22   

    Set TestRS = DBConn.GetRecordset(adCmdStoredProc, strSQL)
```

I get data back. I need to be able to either pass NULLs or actual data to the @FranID and @Type. This is driving me insane any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but why even bother adding the parameters that are `NULL` as they have a default value already specified in your stored proc? If you don't add them you will avoid this issue.

Comment: Try using `DBNull.Value` (or whatever the VB6 equivalent is) instead of `NULL`.

Comment: The better approach is to not set the parameter as @MartinParkin has already suggested. I use this method all the time when I have defaults set on the stored procedure.

Comment: @yelxe there isn't one unless you mean `vbNull` which isn't the same thing plus the OP is talking VBScript not VB6 they are not the same thing.

Comment: You can test this using SQL profiler to see what gets passed but it likely does `EXEC dbo.getstuff 1, 22, default` which will pass `default` as `null` so in effect it is doing the same thing even if you think it isn't.

Comment: @All You are right. I should just not set the parameter as is suggested. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should just not set the parameter as is suggested.